# C# Check if JSON response contains key

Tags: c#, json

I'm making an HTTP request that returns JSON but depending if the request is successful or not then the fields returned are different.

Consider the following snippet:

```
WebResponse response = moveItemRequest.GetResponse();
string stringResponse = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    stringResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

// deserialize json response
MoveItemResponse moveItemResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MoveItemResponse>(stringResponse);
```

The `MoveItemResponse` class:

```
public class MoveItemResponse
{
    public string code;
    public string reason;
    public IList<ItemInfo> ItemInfo;
    public MoveItemResponse()
    {
        ItemInfo = new List<ItemInfo>();
    }
}
```

How am I able to check if a specific field is returned? Depending on if the request is successful then either code & reason will be returned, else itemInfo will be returned (where itemInfo is an object).

Fail Response:

```
{
   "reason":"unlucky",
   "message":null,
   "code":460
}
```

Successful Response:

```
{
   "errorState":null,
   "credits":6310,
   "itemInfo":[
      {
         "tradeId":717011415,
         "itemData":{
            "id":101619602325,
            "timestamp":1447170628,
            "formation":"f3412",
            "untradeable":false,
            "assetId":158023,
            "rating":94,
            "itemType":"player",
            "resourceId":-2147325625,
            "owners":1,
            "discardValue":752,
            "itemState":"forSale",
            "cardsubtypeid":3,
            "lastSalePrice":0,
            "morale":50,
            "fitness":99,
            "injuryType":"none",
            "injuryGames":0,
            "preferredPosition":"RW",
            "statsList":[
               {
                  "value":0,
                  "index":0
               },
               {
                  "value":0,
                  "index":1
               },
               {
                  "value":0,
                  "index":2
               },
               {
                  "value":0,
                  "index":3
               },
               {
                  "value":0,
                  "index":4
               }
            ],
            "lifetimeStats":[
               {
                  "value":0,
                  "index":0
               },
               {
                  "value":0,
                  "index":1
               },
               {
                  "value":0,
                  "index":2
               },
               {
                  "value":0,
                  "index":3
               },
               {
                  "value":0,
                  "index":4
               }
            ],
            "training":0,
            "contract":7,
            "suspension":0,
            "attributeList":[
               {
                  "value":92,
                  "index":0
               },
               {
                  "value":88,
                  "index":1
               },
               {
                  "value":86,
                  "index":2
               },
               {
                  "value":95,
                  "index":3
               },
               {
                  "value":24,
                  "index":4
               },
               {
                  "value":62,
                  "index":5
               }
            ],
            "teamid":241,
            "rareflag":1,
            "playStyle":250,
            "leagueId":53,
            "assists":0,
            "lifetimeAssists":0,
            "loyaltyBonus":1,
            "pile":5,
            "nation":52
         },
         "tradeState":"active",
         "buyNowPrice":1726000,
         "currentBid":0,
         "offers":0,
         "watched":null,
         "bidState":"none",
         "startingBid":426000,
         "confidenceValue":100,
         "expires":3212,
         "sellerName":"FIFA UT",
         "sellerEstablished":0,
         "sellerId":0,
         "tradeOwner":false
      }
   ],
   "duplicateItemIdList":null,
   "bidTokens":{

   },
   "currencies":[
      {
         "name":"COINS",
         "funds":6310,
         "finalFunds":6310
      },
      {
         "name":"POINTS",
         "funds":0,
         "finalFunds":0
      },
      {
         "name":"DRAFT_TOKEN",
         "funds":0,
         "finalFunds":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Secondly, do I need to do the StreamReader to declare the returned JSON to a string before deserializing it?

Comment: Please paste sample of both the JSON (pass and fail) to help you better.

Comment: Usually HTTP 200 OK or similar status code will mean a MoveItemResponse object will be delivered while a fail status code will usually imply a Code + Reason response. See if you can switch to [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) so you have access to [EnsureSuccessStatusCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode(v=vs.118).aspx) to check that automatically, else use [this table for comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Comment: HTTP 200 OK is still returned for both responses as the request was successful even if the action was not.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are couple of ways to handle this, like:

- Do `IndexOf` inside the string and decide if the property is there or not?

For example:

```
if (response.IndexOf("\"code\":", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > 0) /*assumption properties are inside double quotes*/
{
    //Do things for error   
}
else
{
    //Do things for success
}
```

- Have a class which has properties for both success and failure case and now based on the property representing the value for Error decide whether it passed or not

For example:

```
var instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
if (instance.code != 0)
{
    //Do things for error
}
else
{
    //Do things for success
}
```

I have tried to do the second option with the below code so give this code a try. I have created mock classes based on your sample data using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). I hope I have understood your question.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var responses = new string[] { @"{""reason"":""unlucky"",""message"":null,""code"":460}",
            @"{""errorState"":null,""credits"":6310,""itemInfo"":[{""tradeId"":717011415,""itemData"":{""id"":101619602325
            ,""timestamp"":1447170628,""formation"":""f3412"",""untradeable"":false,""assetId"":158023,""rating"":94,""itemType""
            :""player"",""resourceId"":-2147325625,""owners"":1,""discardValue"":752,""itemState"":""forSale"",""cardsubtypeid""
            :3,""lastSalePrice"":0,""morale"":50,""fitness"":99,""injuryType"":""none"",""injuryGames"":0,""preferredPosition""
            :""RW"",""statsList"":[{""value"":0,""index"":0},{""value"":0,""index"":1},{""value"":0,""index"":2},{""value"":0,""index""
            :3},{""value"":0,""index"":4}],""lifetimeStats"":[{""value"":0,""index"":0},{""value"":0,""index"":1},{""value"":0,""index""
            :2},{""value"":0,""index"":3},{""value"":0,""index"":4}],""training"":0,""contract"":7,""suspension"":0,""attributeList""
            :[{""value"":92,""index"":0},{""value"":88,""index"":1},{""value"":86,""index"":2},{""value"":95,""index"":3},{""value""
            :24,""index"":4},{""value"":62,""index"":5}],""teamid"":241,""rareflag"":1,""playStyle"":250,""leagueId"":53,""assists""
            :0,""lifetimeAssists"":0,""loyaltyBonus"":1,""pile"":5,""nation"":52},""tradeState"":""active"",""buyNowPrice"":1726000
            ,""currentBid"":0,""offers"":0,""watched"":null,""bidState"":""none"",""startingBid"":426000,""confidenceValue"":100
            ,""expires"":3212,""sellerName"":""FIFA UT"",""sellerEstablished"":0,""sellerId"":0,""tradeOwner"":false}],""duplicateItemIdList""
            :null,""bidTokens"":{},""currencies"":[{""name"":""COINS"",""funds"":6310,""finalFunds"":6310},{""name"":""POINTS""
            ,""funds"":0,""finalFunds"":0},{""name"":""DRAFT_TOKEN"",""funds"":0,""finalFunds"":0}]}" };

            foreach (var response in responses)
            {
                var instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
                if (instance.code != 0)
                {
                    //Do things for error
                }
                else
                {   
                    //Do things for success
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class StatsList
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public int index { get; set; }
    }

    public class LifetimeStat
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public int index { get; set; }
    }

    public class AttributeList
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public int index { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemData
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public int timestamp { get; set; }
        public string formation { get; set; }
        public bool untradeable { get; set; }
        public int assetId { get; set; }
        public int rating { get; set; }
        public string itemType { get; set; }
        public int resourceId { get; set; }
        public int owners { get; set; }
        public int discardValue { get; set; }
        public string itemState { get; set; }
        public int cardsubtypeid { get; set; }
        public int lastSalePrice { get; set; }
        public int morale { get; set; }
        public int fitness { get; set; }
        public string injuryType { get; set; }
        public int injuryGames { get; set; }
        public string preferredPosition { get; set; }
        public List<StatsList> statsList { get; set; }
        public List<LifetimeStat> lifetimeStats { get; set; }
        public int training { get; set; }
        public int contract { get; set; }
        public int suspension { get; set; }
        public List<AttributeList> attributeList { get; set; }
        public int teamid { get; set; }
        public int rareflag { get; set; }
        public int playStyle { get; set; }
        public int leagueId { get; set; }
        public int assists { get; set; }
        public int lifetimeAssists { get; set; }
        public int loyaltyBonus { get; set; }
        public int pile { get; set; }
        public int nation { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemInfo
    {
        public int tradeId { get; set; }
        public ItemData itemData { get; set; }
        public string tradeState { get; set; }
        public int buyNowPrice { get; set; }
        public int currentBid { get; set; }
        public int offers { get; set; }
        public object watched { get; set; }
        public string bidState { get; set; }
        public int startingBid { get; set; }
        public int confidenceValue { get; set; }
        public int expires { get; set; }
        public string sellerName { get; set; }
        public int sellerEstablished { get; set; }
        public int sellerId { get; set; }
        public bool tradeOwner { get; set; }
    }

    public class BidTokens
    {
    }

    public class Currency
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int funds { get; set; }
        public int finalFunds { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string reason { get; set; }
        public object message { get; set; }
        public int code { get; set; }


        public object errorState { get; set; }
        public int credits { get; set; }
        public List<ItemInfo> itemInfo { get; set; }
        public object duplicateItemIdList { get; set; }
        public BidTokens bidTokens { get; set; }
        public List<Currency> currencies { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Contains Error: {code != 0}";
        }
    }
}
```